# SSL certificate: suggestions for choosing the CA

Tags: ssl-certificate

I am running a public web application.

I would like to get a SSL certificate from a CA.

Have you got any suggestions or a CA that you are happy of using (or the opposite)?

What are the things I should be careful about?

My requirements are:
_ it must be recognized by all browsers (desktop and **mobile**)
_ it must be not too expensive (up to 60$/year)

Can I get something good with that money?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

GoDaddy does reasonably priced certs for what you're looking for.

Comment: +1. If you ask me, whether GoDaddy, Thawte, or Verisign, any one is as good as another and the primary factor is cost. GoDaddy appears to be the least expensive of the 3.